# Editing a video

Tags: linux, ubuntu, video, ffmpeg, concatenation

I used OpenShot Video Editor to concatenate a few videos of a vacation I recently went on. However, the first 18 seconds of the video is upside down; the rest of it is fine.

Even though I am using Ubuntu 14.04, I consider myself somewhat of a beginner in respect to my skills with Linux. I have attempted to use FFMPEG, to no avail.

It would be great if someone on this site can please assist me and guide me in fixing the video.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Do the first 18 seconds show upright in OpenShot?

Comment: @Mulvya Nope. It is upside down, just as it is when I watch it in VLC player.

Comment: Looks like the video has a rotation tag. So, you'll need to [rotate](http://www.openshotusers.com/help/1.3/en/ar01s13.html#sect2_55) it 180.